# How do I make my textures show in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing

I am admittedly new to Blender, and of course cycles. I am working on a scene and I have textures set to my objects that render with internal engine just fine. However, when I go into cycles, everything is greyish. I have two light sources that should be sufficient (I think), I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. This is a screenshot of the cycles result. [image: Cycles rendering interior]

Comment: The materials from bender internal will not translate to cycles. You need to recreate them. read http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because in Cycles you have to apply the texures differently from blender internal.
To apply a texture in Cycles you have to go to the materials tab, click on the (dot)button next to color and choose Image Texture and finally open your Texture.[image][image][image]