# keeping UV textures going from Cycles to Blender Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

So, i wanna keep my UV maps moving to Blender Render. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Your UV maps will be preserved, but Cycles and BI have different ways of handling the textures themselves. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34544/599