# Imported .obj just showing a black texture

Tags: texturing, import

I downloaded a 3d object online and when I imported to blender the whole object just has a black texture. I do have the correct textures in png but I don't know how to use them.
Here are some pictures.

[image: blender]

This is what the download included

[image: blender]

Comment: The model was badly converted/exported and there are no textures in the material assigned to the object. Best shot would be to find some way to open the max file then export it again.

Comment: I am afraid you will have to give textures to everything yourself in blender

Comment: As you don't have materials anyway you can change your Render to Cycles unless there is a reason to stay in Blender Internal. You can see how to apply textures here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34548/15366

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a material. Blender has two different renderers, Blender internal (the old) and Cycles (the new and nowadays standard). Materials are different in these two. I suggest you pick cycles.

First, make sure you are using cycles. You find the menu in the top bar of blender.

[image: switch to cycles]

Now, select the object and go to the Material tab. A material should be selected for the object. If it not, create it:

[image: create material]

If the material was created for Blender Internal, you may have to press "use nodes". Now, your material is ready to accept a texture map. Press the little button with a dot to the far right of the "Color" field. In the menu that pops up, select "Image Texture".

[image: add image texture]

Now hit open and browse to your texture. You have now created a material with a diffuse shader and an image texture. It should look like this:

[image: final shader]

If it doesn't show up on the model, it means your UV-mapping on the model is wrong (probably). Since the texture only works for a specific UV-mapping, you must get this right when you import.

The next step if you intend to render this is to work on the shader some more. You do this in the node editor. Your shader will look like this:

[image: node editor]

Comment: The model does have a material, http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=161554128 but it was exported and shared badly so the obj has no links to the textures. Also, Blender Render is much faster and recommended for beginners.

Comment: @iKlsR  I would strongly disagree with the statement that beginners should use BI.  Cycles and BI are different, it depends on the application which one should be used.  I personally started on cycles and still use it exclusively because I like ray tracing.  I don't think Cycles is more/less complicated, it's just different.

Comment: @PGmath We could discuss this for hours. There are several reasons, one being not everyone is running a mid to high range system (think old pentiums or amd cards) so expect wait times upwards not to mention fireflies and other notorious beginner issues. Also being that the model is already textured, just add a hemi lamp and its ready to go. Using context it's fair to assume that these types of questions have to do with practicing animation and or modding.

Answer (score 0):

If you imported an object and it showed up black in Solid Mode, check the settings under materials and change the viewport color to white. usually, this is black when you import an object that came from a different software.
[image]