# Cycle renders in gray (no color)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]Hello,

The blender render does give color but not the cycle. How could this be?
Is it maybe because of my GPU? (wich i cant select as compute device)

[image]

Comment: I do have RGBA checked in the output section..

Comment: Did you set up your materials for cycles? Materials for blender internal can't be used when rendering on cycles.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 5):

First of all: using CPU or GPU would not make any difference on the characteristics of the rendered image, other than rendering faster or slower.

I see three possible reasons why you have a black and white image:

1. You set up materials in blender internal and didn't create materials for cycles.

   When no materials are present cycles will render everything with the default material, which is gray.

Cycles and Blender internal's materials are not compatible or interchangeable. you need to create new ones them using material nodes.

2. Maybe you did set materials but you set the output to render as B&W. Set it to RGB or RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha)

   [image]
3. Maybe you did set the materials correctly and the output to RGB (or RGBA),
   but you set the render layer to use only one material, overriding all of the other materials for the scene:

   [image]

Comment: Ah oke. i did not set specific matterials for cycles. Thanks for the quick and complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Cegaton pointed out, this happens, when you update a scene from blender internal to cycles.

All materials are lost and replaced by a placeholder material that renders gray.

Just go to material tab and start creating new materials.

Edit: I have to correct myself: It is not the case, at least diffuse color is transfered.

Here is a simple scene in blender internal

[image: Internal render with simple materials]

Same in cycles

[image: Same in cycles]

And here is a screenshot of material tab after changing to cycles.
[image: Screenshot of material tab after changing to cycles]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. But even in the preview the matterials are gray (and when i select a colered one it turns gray).. Sorry if its a dumb question.

Comment: Please upload some screenshots. Material tab with the object selected. Render and Render Layer-Tab would also be helpful.

Comment: And: are there textures applied to the object?

Comment: Oke i managed to upload one more screenshot but thats all im allowed to do aparently.. I didnt use textures.

Comment: Does that screenshot tell anything?

Comment: Wierd thing, to me, is that where you can add material there material 17 is green and in the preview its gray..

Comment: Can u add another one? With surface expanded in material tab and probably a screenshot of node editor?

Comment: i seem to have not enough reputations to do that. ill replace the screenshot with a new one..

Comment: My node editor seems to be emty.. is that it?

Comment: Probably. When you expand surface in the material tab, is there a "use nodes" button? If yes, click it an you can start editing your material in the node editor. First i would try to apply a different diffuse color and render it...

Comment: It is not necessary but more convinient to work with. In the surface panel you can change the diffuse color but to use the full power of cycles you have to press "use nodes". This will give you more options and make a node tree available in the node editor.

Comment: well to be honest to me it it isnt convinient to use nodes because its my first time. But just selecting materials and assinging them isnt gona do it for cycles?

Comment: If u have cylces materials from other sources, say linked or appended from an other blend-file, it is possible. But there are no basic materials shipped inside cycles. You have to create them by mixing shaders, adding textures and so on. 

I suggest you should read the node section in the Blender Manual. Nodes are not complicated and give you great flexibility...

Comment: I do have color in the preview now but when i asing it to a plane i still get a gray render..

Comment: What happens when you press shift + z in viewport?

Comment: shift - z doenst seem to do much.. sorry.. Yes it does!

Comment: Try to add another screenshot. There is no limitation on screenshots i believe. Or just delete your second screenshot and add another...

Comment: But.. the F12 render still gives a gray image... Huh?

Comment: We need a screenshot. 

And better add another comment instead of editing your comments when you add further informations. Nobody will understand this discussion when there are informations missing...

Comment: will do.. i did replace the screenshot. it just seems wierd that it does render color in 3d view but not with F12.

Comment: Guys... this is not a forum but a question and answer site. Conversations like this should go to chat

Comment: please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: sorry first timer. And when presented with the chat option the site told me i didnt have enough reputations..

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be missing material nodes in Cycles. I'll suggest reading the Blender Manual for materials and nodes in Cycles here: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/introduction.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution to your problem.

Try "Cntrl + Alt + B"

This is called the 'Render Border'.

I accidentally "created" a render border. This is why my Cycles was grey.

It's not a color or material problem.

This feature is used to render only a selected amount of your screen, just in case you need to save on render time.

I guess I accidentally pressed "cntrl + B" and created a tiny sliver of a border instead of a square (which is why I didn't know I had this feature on).

"Cntrl + B" activates the feature. Click and drag to create a border and your render shows inside of the shape you make.

To turn the feature off completely, just press "Cntrl + Alt + B".

Now, the border is removed and your render is back to normal.