# How do I fix this Traceback error for Massive Material Nodes?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on, conversion

I'm trying to convert my material from Blender Render so it can be used in Cycles Render, but I get this error when trying to use the addon for this. Can this be fixed or is there a different addon I could use?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a tech support question... and very poorly asked, at that,

Comment: if it is a poorly asks, then its a question, i'm still learning like you don't you think?

Answer (score 2):

The script you are trying to use was written to work with blender 2.66 or earlier, in 2.67 the python api changed in regards to creating new nodes.

Where the script has `shader = TreeNodes.nodes.new('BSDF_DIFFUSE')` it should be changed to `shader = TreeNodes.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')`. There will be other similar changes needed. A list of old and new node names can be [found here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BAC/browse/master/online_mat_lib/__init__.py$43). Chances are there are also other changes that will also need to be done to get the script working.

As the cycles material converter is still in the contrib addons, chances are that one still works. Try the tips I gave in your [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/52138/935) about that script before trying to update this older script.