# Blender plane effect from blender render to cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, effects

[image][image]

On blender render it looks like this but when i try to do it in cycles it doesnt look the same(effect from deviantart) its a bunch of planes with an image to make an effect, Please help.

Comment: Could you post an image of the cycles result?

Comment: Yeah sure give me a minute or two

Comment: As they are different  two render engines, you'll need to "convert" your materials. You can give a try with the solution proposed [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles). If you still have trubles in figuring it out, I suggest you to post the material's settings/node tree so we can heve a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better not to give up to ready to use tools but just once learn how the transparency work in cycles, and then just use the knowledge.

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=transparent+textures+in+cycles

It's fairly easy. All you need is your png image's Alpha output as a mix node Factor to mix your image color in a Diffuse shader and a Transparent shader.