# Where did my texture go after selecting Use Nodes?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

1. I created a material for the Cube

   - Color map
   - Normal map
2. Unwrapped it
3. Enjoyed the view in the viewport with Internal and the Game Engine
4. Then I switched to Cycles and clicked on Use nodes and there is no more texture in the viewport of Internal and Game Engine

What happened? Can I undo that somehow? I read that Cycles's is not compatible with Internal.
Can I have materials set for Internal/GE and Cycles and switch between them (the rendering engines)?

I intend to export my creations to my own game engine and eventually to render still images for enjoyment but the former is what I need most.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 1):

Materials created for Blender Internal are not compatible with Cycles. Blender Internal uses an entirely different nodes system, stemming from the fact that it is an entirely different rendering engine and rendering images via an entirely different method.

To use your texture in Cycles, you would need to recreate your texture in Cycles, or otherwise use a script to convert it to Cycles. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles) for more information.

Comment: This is something I already understand. My question is that after I clicked Use Node and went back to Blender Render/GE the texture would not display. The material is there but there is no texture in the viewport to be seen. Why would adding nodes in Cycles break what I have setup in BR/GE?

Comment: By pressing add nodes you basically 'converted' the Blender Internal material to a Cycles one, possibly breaking it for both engines, since the conversion is not really complete or reliably. Choose one engine and stick with it, create materials from scratch for each and avoid switching back and forth, that will only lead to misfortune.