# converting blender internal to cycles material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

with the reference [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

[Addon](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/qubodup/d3fc78f0aadb1df5581b76f4d556d25d/raw/503da6128aba533f11d6f2ed8d6c931ebb2dae5f/materials_cycles_converter.py)

I have download and installed the addon but its not working with my material. After clicking or converting to cycles I did not get the same result. Its just having diffuse material nothing else. As seen in the Blender internal it not having the same result similar in cycles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Addon? Which version? What *exactly* you are trying to do?

Comment: @brockmann yes internal to cycles addon link given in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

Comment: @masterj2001 i have link above in the question its duplicate question but with that addon im not getting the result plz note

Answer (score 2):

The addon don't seems to convert textures for now. These options mentioned in the wiki ("check "Extract Alpha Textures" and "Extract Procedural Textures" respectively") have been disabled in the script, probably because they are not finished yet (the addon is still in Beta).

You can easily do a manual bake of the Color and Normal and recreate a simple Cycles material with those two maps.