# Object looks different when rendering in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

The object doesn't have any texture, only with color.
I changed it to Cycles and it looks like the following picture.
I have many objects and some appear this problem.

[image]
What is wrong with this apple?

Comment: Did you change it to cycles after setting materials in blender render?

Comment: I had change it.

Comment: It looks like there are two apples in each others with different materials. Check the outliner.

Comment: Materials in cycles and blender internal are not interchangeable. You need to create new materials if you change render engines.

Comment: Read: [how is cycles different from blender internal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/how-is-cycles-different-from-blender-internal)

Comment: And: [how do I convert materials from blender internal to cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)