# can I install Blender internal render engine into 2.8 so I can open my old projects incompatible with Cycles and Evee?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

Or if you know a better solution please share. I just can`t switch between 2.8 and 2.79 fluently because of changes, so I want to move to 2.8 completely

Comment: Another way to go  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep using Blender Internal, you'll have to use Blender 2.79 and prior versions. You cannot add the old render engine back into 2.8.

Comment: its not that Im a die-hard BI fan, its just all materials were done in it and when I import project in Evee or Cyles, theyre all gone, and I`ll have to recreate em from the scratch. Anyway, a pity. Thanks

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to (someday) add/compile the "Blender Internal" (or similar) engine back into Blender 2.8+? Blender "Internal Shaders" where the only ones that worked with .fbx export (to my knowledge); they were dead simple to translate. Now Blender 2.8 has lost all ability to export entire models to the Unity game engine. This is why Blender 2.79 will probably never die.

Comment: @Logic1 You can export FBX with a material using textures plugged into the Principled BSDF. For more information [consult the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/io_node_shaders_info.html).

Comment: @Robert Gützkow  In 2.79 I may keep my rendering node setups separate from a basic set of parameters for exports. That makes 2.79 more powerful. In 2.8+ you must maintain multiple node setups for rendering and exporting (how do I switch between them efficiently?). I think it's a nightmare regardless what the manual may suggest. Please consider how a simple set of basic parameters (like the internal fields) could easily add so much more value to Blender 2.8. I know no one will listen or care, but I see a glorious future in it..

Comment: That is a shame. Cycles is the only rendering engine which can bake in 2.8, and it is missing some very important features like alpha/transparency support. This is a huge misstep.

Comment: @HugoZink you should be able to render a transmission pass.

Comment: So render the alpha to a separate texture? That really shouldn't be necessary. Blender internal just allowed me to painlessly atlas 6 different transparent textures together into 1, so I could use them in Unity. I have to export the texture for use in Unity, so making nodes that treat a separate texture as alpha will not work. Blender is currently *without* a renderer that supports transparent texture baking, and that is a huge mistake.