# UV Mappings to Material

Tags: materials, uv

Blender 2.79b.
Following situation:
New at Blender.
I made a model which is complete. I have create UV mappings for this model, which are complete. I am using multiple texture image files.
In 3D view, I can see the model exactly how it's supposed to be. Now, because I want to export it to Unity, I need to still apply a material, otherwise non of the texture mapping will take.
Currently there are no textures or materials linked with that model.
I just want to take my UV mappings and make it somehow into a simple lambert shader with multiple texture files or whatever. Or maybe multiple shaders, I wasn't aware using multiple textures files makes it more complicated, if true.

But in any case, I can't find a way to just apply all of this and make a material from it.
Also Blender Render shows everything correct while Cycles Render shows no textures. And of course rendering the model does not produce any textures because there is no material.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert materials from Blender Internal to Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles)

Comment: *"I need to still apply a material, otherwise non of the texture mapping will take"* as you unwrapped the model it already has texture mapping and it will be transferred into Unity when exported into file formats allowing that (fbx, dae etc). When you have texture for that mapping it should work same as in Blender. Shader should be added in the end-application (Unity in this case)

Comment: It appears without textures, materials or shaders when imported in Unity (FBX). So I feel like it needs a material.

@rjg Possibly? But I don't even know what the Cycles Render is. I know it exists but that's it. I really just want to export.

Comment: As already mentioned - export mesh with UV map. Texture map can be baked if it's not enough to provide original image (e.g. if you edited something in material settings and didn't just put an image onto the mesh), see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13508/how-do-i-bake-a-texture-using-cycles-bake (for Cycles though). There won't be any material from Blender in Unity so don't spend time adding it, material will be added in Unity and set up to use texture based on UV coordinates.