# When I turn on cycle render, object turns all white w/ no color, any help? (ver 2.79)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I don't know what to do. I'm really new.[image]

Comment: Materials created in blender internal are different than those in cycles. You need to create new ones.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/364/how-do-i-convert-materials-from-blender-internal-to-cycles

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that somehow you probably added a material in the "Override" section inside the "View Layer Properties" tab.[image]

Comment: I don't see the override tab or material changes. I'm using blender 2.79b. What can I do?